# Read a line from file, replace line to another file

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to Linux scripting.
I need the lines from a file, and one by one write it in a specific line of another file.

**Example:**

File1.txt:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

File2.txt:

```
abc
abc
xxx
```

I need to write first "line1" instead of the 3rd line of File2.txt, then do some operations with this file, then write "line2" instead of the 3rd line of File2.txt and so on.

At the moment this is what I have

```
    for n in {1..5} 
do
    a=$(sed '24!d' File1) #read string 24
    echo $a
    sed -i '1s/.*/a/' File2.txt

done
```

Now instead of 24 in line 3 i should put the variable n used in the cycle. Is it possible?
The same thing is in line 5, where >"a" is supposed to be a variable, but the program changes the first line of File2.txt with "a".
Can I use this functions or I need to use other functions (if yes what functions?)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: You need to research shell arithmetic,  loops, `read`, and redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
sed '2r t2' t1
```

If you want to perform any operation on file 2 you can simply use

```
sed 2r<(cat t2) t1  ##You can change command (cat t2) as per your need
```

I think this will solve your problem.

```
root@ubuntu:~/T/e/s/t# cat t1
test
asdf
xyza
root@ubuntu:~/T/e/s/t# cat t2
sample line 1
sample line 2
sample line 3
sample line 4
root@ubuntu:~/T/e/s/t# sed 2r<(cat t2) t1
test
asdf
sample line 1
sample line 2
sample line 3
sample line 4
xyza
```

**Details**

2: Second line

r: read from the file

If you want to commit this operation, you can use sed -i option. Refer to [man sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) for more details.

Thanks, [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) for missing scenario (sed '2r t2' t1)

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the question is asking (hard to tell, as there is no desired output), but if you do this, why are you using process substitution? You could use `sed '2r t2' t1` instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm using process substitution because if some operation(sed,awk,grep etc) need to be made in second file it will be easy to do it. You can make many possible scenario as per your need.